# How to create dataset in chart.js dynamically using array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I am trying to create a whole dataset of a chart using chart.js, but I am getting duplicate records in my array. Here is my javascript code:

```
mdistid = [];
distdata = [];
datasetValue = [];
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    glc = mdistid[i];
    distdata.length = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < mthlen; j++) {
        mth = marr[j];
        switch (mth) {
            case '1':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty1' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '2':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty2' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '3':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty3' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '4':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty4' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '5':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty5' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '6':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty6' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '7':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty7' + glc).val();
                break;
            case '8':
                distdata[j] = $('#qty8' + glc).val();
                break;
        }
    }
    datasetValue[i] = {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: distdata
    };
}
```

The problem is that array `datasetValue` is only getting the last data value in the whole array. E.g. if last value of the data is 5,10 it fills the same value in all the array...

Comment: Can you change "distdata = [];" place  in "for" pls?

Comment: i think there is no need to change the place of disdata[]; in for loop.......... why do  u feel that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you would take `glc = mdistid[i]` while array `mdistid` is clearly empty. That's why your selector `$('#qty1' + glc)` fail.

Also, you can use string concatenation on jQuery selector, e.g.: `distdata[j] = $('#qty' + mth + glc).val();`.

You could provide some data, and we can't guess what's possibly inside `marr` and `mathlen`.

Comment: no actually mdistd[] and marr[] is holding somedata every time and the loop don't fails........ my problem is that when i get out from the look of for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){} i get the data of the array distdata[] and i pass this data to my  datasetValue[i]={dataset:disdata} but after both the loop finish when i check datasetValue array in all the index the data is remains same

Comment: for e.g.: suppose when the outer loop runs 2 time and the inner loop runs 3 time and my datasetValue sholud be like this after the end of both loops
    datasetValue[0]={ label: "My Second dataset", fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)", strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",       highlightFill:"rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",highlightStroke:"rgba(151,187,205,1)",data: [500,300.200] }; and datasetValue[1]={label: "My Second dataset",fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",data: [200,100.250]};

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the scope of array `distdata = []` was causing issues. Got placed it before the inner loop and it works.

Comment: I said you that was about  "distdata = [];". Whatever :D